Error trying to commit code via this app for the first time
I've got some GitHub repositories that I've been working on code via the web interface for years, now I'm trying to use a local editor instead.
I downloaded & installed Visual Studio Code via the Windows store, and went through the setup process, including installing Git, and cloning a repository.  I make a trivial test change, and try to commit the change back to GitHub.  At which point I get the error:

git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet
error: there was a problem with the editor '"c:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\git-editor.sh"'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

What's gone wrong, and how do I fix it?
Doing a bit of googling, I found the following suggestions, tried them, and neither made any change:
git config --global core.editor "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
git config --global core.editor "c:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\git-editor.sh"
(If those are also going to be a problem, what do I need to do to revert them?).

....  And supplying a commit message fixes it.  That feels like something the GUI should catch & supply a clearer error message for.
Or just have a default message, like committing via the GitHub web interface does.
